# For running a search query on data stored in Oracle db, is using REGEXP in PL/SQL faster than fetching all the data and filtering it in Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, jdbc, plsql

Basically trying to compare performance for tables with a few thousand rows that required to be filtered on non-indexed columns using PL/SQL's REGEX function with java...regex plus the overhead of sending more data over the network between database and the application server.

Comment: The only way to answer this is to measure both methods and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing the regex filter within PL/SQL will absolutely be faster. Performing the data reduction closest to the data generally results in the best performance (especially when compared to sending data "over the wire"), not to mention the fact that PL/SQL, in most cases, outperforms Java, even Java stored procedures within the database itself.